# Cant read data from TCP Server with Android Client APP

Tags: java, android, tcp, client

That is my program in java for my android app. I tried to create tcp connection with tcp server. I can connect to server with another applications so that i can send and receive from tcp server. With my code and with my program i can send messages to server very eazy, but i have troubles with receiving messages from server.

```
private  Socket socket;
private  final int SERVERPORT = 6060;    
private  final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.8";
public  TextView tv;
private PrintWriter out;
private InputStream in;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

}
```

Here is my problem i dont know how to receive strings or bytes from server. When i run my app on phone it closes the open window and say that program stop working. If i delete this section of code(public void ONCLICK2) i can transmit messages to server.

```
  public void   ONCLICK2(View view)  {

       try {
        in=socket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        byte array[]=new byte[1];
        try {
            int i=in.read(array);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
```

So please help me with that section of code. How can i receive string send from TCP server.

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String str = et.getText().toString();

                    out.println(str);
                    out.flush();

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


class ClientThread implements Runnable {

     @Override
            public void run() {

               try {
                   InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                    true);



           } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

         }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the problem is you are intercepting the byte array of an unknown length and attempting to store them in array the size of one. Furthermore, it is ideal to append the packet size prior to the data in the packet and perhaps create the intercept in a separate thread waiting for incoming packets.

To just fix your ONCLICK2 you should do the following:

```
byte[] data = new byte[6556];
try {
   in = socket.getInputStream();
   // NOTE: The data byte array will contain empty values if
   // under the size of 6556
   int size = in.read(data);

   // send to LogCat
   Log.e("String", data.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have not tested this code, but this should fix your problem.

Comment: Now i accept some packets but i cant recognize them. How can i create seperate thread for incoming packets and show them in textview or something like that.